# How to use a renamed enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, enums

**In Rails, how can I effectively change an enum "key" ?**

I have an enum for :status on an orders model.

In app/models/order.rb

> enum status: [:new_order, :processing, :delivered_to_customer,
>   :cancelled]

I have seeded records with various statuses.  I've recently changed the name of one of the statuses from "delivered_to_customer" to "delivered".

> enum status: [:new_order, :processing, :delivered, :cancelled]

In Rails console, when I look at an order which previously had the "delivered_to_customer" status, it still does. 
`order.delivered_to_customer? >> true`
`order.delivered?  >> 'undefined method' error`

Is there any way to update the getters and setters for enums, since it's just integers stored in the db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you didn't reload console after changing values in model. Try reload console.

Because enum generate methods run time, when you start server or console.

You can check documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html).

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  I had been doing the console command: reload! thinking that was sufficient - but quitting out and going back in was what was needed.